# HttpClient post form with optional upload files

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

I have a web form with several options for uploading photos (up to 10). `ContentType` set to "multipart/form-data". I know how to upload just one file, but have no idea how to create `HttpContent` for other 9 optional? Creating `MultipartContent` with appropriate `ContentDisposition` header gave no luck. At very best I got:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="bla bla bla";
```

Or, if I add parameters to `ContentDisposition` header:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="bla bla bla"; filename;
```

I need to send post request with empty content for optional upload files like this:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="bla bla bla"; filename=""
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: use Wireshark or Fiddler together with a browser to see how the correct HTTP content looks like and then reproduce it in code...

Comment: I know how the correct request looks like. The problem is how to add parameter "filename" in ContentDispostion. Empty or null values throw exception "invalid argument" ...

Comment: I mean parameter "filename" with empty value.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly... sorry.

Comment: Parameter "filename" appears in Content-Disposition header only if I actually add some payload, like StreamContent. In this case I have a correct Content-Disposition header. I want to know how create some HttpContent without actual payload but with Content-Disposition header like this: form-data; name="contentName"; filename="" ?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I don't know if it is a best solution for my question, but at least it works:
1. Create new class for HttpContent (subclass from `HttpContent`).
2. Initialize `Content-Disposition` header.
3. Override two methods `TryComputeLength`(return false) and `SerializeToStreamAsync`(just a stub for serialization task).

Now this class can be added to `MultipartFormDataContent`.
And http request content looks like:

```
----------[boundary string]
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="formFieldName"; filename=""

----------[boundary string]
```